# Best practice to write a ROS service for a serial-communication class with many options

Tags: ros, cameras, serial

I have been asked to write code to implement serial communications with a camera in order to control its pedestal (movable base) as well as set a few dozen other camera options. The catch is that I have to make it usable by ROS.

What would be the best practice to implement this functionality in ROS? I understand  the concept of services, but I think that there should be a better way than creating a different service/file for each option.

Thanks,
Daniel.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org/questions/) because it is only about ROS and not specifically robotics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write a subscription based node? It could take messages from whoever then passes the information on to the camera. From what you've said, it seems like a service wouldn't be necessary.

Response. Yes. Create a new message that has all the necessary fields and a new topic, maybe /camera_parameters.

Comment: This does seem like a better idea. Would you suggest creating a topic with all the parameters?